# WR GFCI or WR outlet for outside use ( for US)

Tags: receptacle, gfci, weather

I want to replace the outside receptacles around my house. These outlets are originally Weather Resistant with a cover ( Not GFCI). In the upstream of this circuit, there is a GFCI outlet, which is inside the garage.

My Question is,

1. Should I replace all outside receptacles with weather resistant outlets by keeping GFCI at the upstream ( in the Garage)?
2. Or Should I replace all outside receptacles with Weather resistant GFCI outlets. If yes, Is it OK to keep the GFCI at the upstream (inside the garage)?

Thank You!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely option 1 - **keep the GFCI upstream**.

You do need to make sure the upstream GFCI is wired properly. You can do that by installing the replacement receptacles and make sure they work. Then press *TEST* on the upstream GFCI. If you lose power on the outside receptacles and get power back with *RESET* then all is good. If you don't lose power with *TEST* then either the GFCI is faulty or, far more likely, the wiring at the GFCI/receptacle is incorrect. If there is a problem, take pictures of the wiring at the GFCI/receptacle and start a new question for troubleshooting.

There are two reasons to keep things as is (except upgrading to new weather resistant receptacles):

- GFCI has sensitive electronics which don't handle extreme weather very well. Even if the weather resistant receptacles do a perfect job of keeping water out, the temperature changes will be more of a problem outside than in the garage. So the GFCI inside the garage will last longer than outside.
- Double GFCI does not improve safety. Plus, unless rewired as single GFCI (by rewiring the feed from the GFCI/receptacle in the garage to the outside), there can be confusing/troublesome situations any time there is a GFCI trip on the outside receptacle.

Comment: Even better (assuming the outside outlets currently work) is to test the GFCI function _before_ touching any wiring at all.

Answer (score 4):

Usually one GFCI protection device per circuit.  Saves running around resetting/finding them all.

Weather does stuff that GFCIs don't like.  Moisture/humidly, heat/cold, sun.  They last two or three times as long inside than out.